# Disable AOT for a specific assembly in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios

When deploying to iOS device I get the following error:

> error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly 'test/LibsNet.dll'

There are also warnings indicating that mscorlib cannot be found:

> Warning MT3005: The dependency 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' of the assembly 'LibsApi, Version=3.2.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' was not found. Please review the project's references. (MT3005)
>
> Warning MT3006: Could not compute a complete dependency map for the project. This will result in slower build times because Xamarin.iOS can't properly detect what needs to be rebuilt (and what does not need to be rebuilt). Please review previous warnings for more details. (MT3006)

According to forums, setting *Link all assemblies* sometimes helps to fix this error, but in case with my app that doesn't work.
Is it possible to skip AOT for a given assembly in Xamarin.iOS? As far as I understand I have to write a command in *Additional mtouch arguments*, but I didn't find such a command in [Xamarin API Documentation](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=man%3amtouch%281%29).

I use

- Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4
- Xamarin.iOS 6.4.0.2
- Xamarin Studio 4.0.10
- Xcode 4.5.2

Comment: What is LibsNet.dll? Is it a DLL built for iOS? AOT cannot be disabled and may not be mixed up with "no linking".

Comment: @Krumelur It's a DLL that was created in Visual Studio. There are no errors when using this DLL with Xamarin.Mac and Xamarin.Android. The problem appears only in Xamarin.iOS

Comment: Is it a PCL that is not using any features that are unavailable on iOS? If it isn't a PCL it is pure coincidence that t he DLL works on Android and Mac.